# Copy on middle click and remove selection on copy

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I want you to be able to select the text you want to copy in my program, as well as automatically copy it, in addition to CTRL-C. So example. If I select "this", then that automatically copies it to middle click. This is my code so far. I have been looking at the middle click event but I do not know how to call it.
I will like it as an if statement

this is my code:

```
private void GetAnswer(string clipboardText)
{
  //Loop through all questions and answers
  foreach (question q in questionList)
  {
    //If we have found an answer that is exactly the same show an Notification
    //Startwith zoekt naar alle vragen die matchen vanaf het begin van de zin
    //en Endwith alle vragen die matchen vanaf het eind van de zin
    if (q._question.StartsWith(clipboardText) || q._question.EndsWith(clipboardText))
    {
      ShowNotification(q._question, q._answer);
      break;
    }   
  }
}

private void ShowNotification(string question, string answer)
{
  notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
  notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = question;
  notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = answer;
  notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
  notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  base.WndProc(ref m);
  {
    const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    {
      GetAnswer(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where you want to paste this text? I think u should use some component.... and handle events. U should also give more informations about your question. Its not clear (atleast for me)

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik i updated my code

Comment: Only clipboard viewer windows receive message: WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD.
Have you registered your form as clipboard viewer ? 
Description here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-drawclipboard

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik already did that

Comment: how? update code please.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik 
copying works already as it should. The only thing I want is copy on middle click so let a clipboard gettext on middle click, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I think you have to handle KeyPress event of the form, and check if e.KeyChar is middle button, if yes, call whatever u want.

Comment: can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 1):

I think solution is in handling KeyPress event of the form.
Sample code could look like:

```
     private void form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar==';')
            {
                //call whatever u want here
            }
        }

    private void form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
         {
             //do whatever u want
         }
    }
```

Comment: but I want it if you do a left mouse click.

Comment: i got this error "the name ''e" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: please, update your code in question...  have u added event from designer, or just pasted it to code ?

Comment: I simply want to get output if you select something with Clipboard.GetText

Comment: i want something like this `         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
         {
            GetAnswer(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText));
         }` but i got error the name ''e" does not exist

Comment: Read about c# events and how to define them. Firstly, i would advise you to go Designer, then (right) click properties window on a form. Then you should go to a event page (lighting bolt icon). Then you have to find MouseClick event, and double click it (not the name, double click the blank spot, which is located on right from its name). Then Designer will correctly add event in your code, and u wont have this error. You have it, cause you dont declared parameter 'e'.